# Apache HttpClient - POST to https url secure?

Tags: java, apache, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

i want to do a `HTTP POST` request, which is secured by ssl.

the client is my java program, which is posting to a https-url (https:// ...). the certificate of the website is verified, i am using Apache HttpClient 4.5.1
with a normal post-request and a custom httpclient.

```
    HttpContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE);
    cm.setMaxTotal(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();
    HttpContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

    HttpPost login = new HttpPost("https://example.org"); // example url
    login.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    login.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-
    login.setEntity(new StringEntity(loginData, ContentType.create("application/json", "UTF-8")));

    JSONResponseHandler<JSONObject> rh = new JSONResponseHandler<>();
    JSONObject test = client.execute(login, rh, context);
```

is this sufficend to get a ssl-secured connection or do i have to work with `KeyStore`, `SSLContext` and `SSLConnectionFactory`?

if i have to use those, how would i do this in an efficent way. i only saw examples how to allow self-signed certificates.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: works fine! i am just not sure if the request (and response) are secured by ssl this way. (this is my first java project with http)